# Showing Dialog in SurfaceView

Tags: android, dialog, surfaceview

My game is drawn onto a `SurfaceView`. I am using a Dialog as a level completion screen, but cannot get it to show (`Dialog.show()`).

I keep getting the following error:

```
01-30 16:45:34.425: E/AndroidRuntime(3415): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I have a Game class which extends Activity and holds the `SurfaceView`. I think `runOnUiThread()` may be the solution, but after tireless searching have no idea how to implement it inside my `SurfaceView`.

Any help is appreciated and I will post my code if requested (just not sure which bits are actually relevant at the moment)

Comment: The dialog works fine, I called it in the onCreate method of my activity and it was as desired

Comment: `OnCreate` is a Activity method, from the sounds of your explanation you are attempting to execute `Dialog.show()` from the `SurfaceView`. So having it work in `OnCreate` is different then having it called from the `SurfaceView`. Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was just saying that the error is not within the dialog itself. Do you know how I should call it? Thanks for your help by the way, really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to modify the UI thread from a worker thread which will give these errors. To prevent this try making a call to the `runOnUiThread()` method...

```
Game.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        customDialogObject.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking at, I can't access the Game Activity. After a bit more searching though, I managed to stumble across Handler. Which has done the trick. Thanks for your time.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432453/popping-up-a-dialog-from-a-non-ui-thread

Comment: I'm glad I got you looking in the right direction. It seems like the use of `Handler`, `AsyncTask` and other Ui Thread utility methods are often used interchangeably and whether they'll work for your certain situation or not depends on other factors (what kind of class you're calling from).... something I haven't entirely figured out myself and have been burned on more than once. Good luck!

Comment: @AndrewSeymour can you please share your codes where u use the runnable method?